# Directory structure - file and folder classes should know each other?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, class-hierarchy

I encountered a problem with two classes knowing each other when I was trying to create a directory structure similar to this:

[image: Directory structure example]

Here's my `Base` class which includes the common elements of `File` and `Folder`.
Notice that I've left out getters and setters, constructors and destructors, `#include`s and `#define`s and other non-related methods and attributes (=nearly everything) for the sake of this question:

```
class Base {
    private:
        string m_name;
        /* Both File and Folder have a parent,
         * but the parent can only be a Folder */
        Base* m_parent;
};
```

Here's the class `Folder` which works just fine:

```
class Folder : public Base {
    public:
        virtual void addChild(Base* child);
        virtual void removeChild(Base* child);
    private:
        vector<Base*> m_children;
};
```

And then the `File` class has nothing new (other than some file related stuff which is unrelated to my question so I've left them out):

```
class File : public Base {
};
```

Now the header files look ok, nothing weird going on.
However, this is how my constructor's should look like:

```
Base::Base(string name, Base* parent) { ... }
File::File(string name, Base* parent) { ... }
// parent should be of type Folder for Files too
Folder::Folder(string name, Folder* parent) { ... }
```

The problem is obvious.
First of all, the parent should ALWAYS be a `Folder`, it can't be a `File`.
However, I have to use `Base` since `File` and `Base` obviously can't know `Folder`.

Also, since my `Base` and `File` don't know `Folder`, they can't call it's `addChild(Base* child);` method:

```
File::File(string name, Base* parent)
: m_name(name), m_parent(parent)
{
    if (parent) {
        parent->addChild(this); // Base doesn't have addChild()-method
    }
}
```

I'm getting a headache from thinking, how can I get around this problem?

**EDIT:** I don't want a hacky way to get the result I'm looking for, I want to find the bug in my design.
How's this stuff designed for windows or unix?

Comment: What is the use of Base exactly then? Folder's the only thing in your structure, File the only concrete leaf. Why would they need a common base?

Comment: The map is not the territory. Throw the inheritance away. Wrap functions common to file and folder in an interface.

Comment: @Mat Apologies for my extremely late answer, I just ran into someone else having this same problem and remembered this question of mine. They "need" a common base class cause they're 90% related, and if they ain't got a common base class, how am I supposed to create a vector `m_children` inside a folder? It would have to contain two different types, `File`s and `Folder`s.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
class Folder;

class Base {
    protected:
        Base(const string &name, Folder *parent);
    private:
        string m_name;
        Folder *m_parent;
    //no add or remove should go here
};

class Folder : public Base {
    public:
        Folder(const string &name, Folder *parent)
        :Base(name, parent)
        {
        }
        void addChild(Base* child);
        void removeChild(Base* child);
    /*...*/
};

class File : public Base {
    public:
        File(const string &name, Folder *parent)
        :Base(name, parent)
        {
        }
};

inline Base::Base(const string &name, Folder *parent);
:m_name(name), m_parent(parent)
{
    if (parent) {
        parent->addChild(this); // no problem!
    }
}
```